# Changing Background Image With Javascript Based on TOD Error?

Tags: javascript, css

I am attempting to code a webpage whose background changes based on time of day, using javascript. I am aware there are other questions based around this concept, but my code, based on those questions' answers, does not produce results.

```
var background = ","
var time = new Date();
var greeting = '';
var hour = time.getHours();
   if (hour < 6 || hour === 12) {
      greeting = "Goodnight!";
        background = 'assignment02_images/backgrounds/night.png';
     }
     else if (hour >= 6 && hour <12) {
      greeting = "Good Morning!";
        background = 'assignment02_images/backgrounds/morning.png';
    }
    else if (hour >=12 && hour < 18 ) {
      greeting = "Good Afternoon!";
        background = 'assignment02_images/backgrounds/afternoon.png';
    }
    else {
      greeting = "Good Evening!";
        background = 'assignment02_images/backgrounds/evening.png';
    }
```

The greeting variable works, which is why I thought the background image should too. However, I don't know what I need to put in document.write() in order to get the background to show up. Currently this just displays a white background.

Comment: Is this function called automatically time to time all day?

Comment: I'm not using functions yet, i need to use document.write i think

Comment: The document.write is just for writing the background, how would you trigger write function?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="bg" id="bgImg"></div>
```

In your scriipt file

```
var dt = new Date()

setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(dt.getHours())
    if (dt.getHours() >= 1 && dt.getHours() <= 6) {
        document.getElementById("bgImg").style.backgroundImage = "url('https://dummyimage.com/300x200/345fa1/fff')"
    } else if (dt.getHours() >= 6 && dt.getHours() <= 12){
        document.getElementById("bgImg").style.backgroundImage = "url('https://dummyimage.com/300x200/a13557/fff')"
    }
}, 30)
```

Just check time between hours and add it into timeout

[Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/gaurav24592/ptc2uLqe/21/)